# Extending continuous functioms defined on the irrationals

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Lavrentieff proved a Theorem which implies that every real valued continuous function defined on a dense subset $D\subseteq \mathbb R$ admits a continuous extension to some $G_\delta $ subset of $\mathbb R$.  See Theorem (4.3.20) in "General Topology" by Engelking, or this [Mathematics Stack Exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127374/extending-a-continuous-function-defined-on-the-rationals).

If the dense subset $D$ is already a $G_\delta $, such as the set of irrational numbers, Lavrentieff's Theorem of course says nothing.  So let us be a bit more audacious:

> Given a real valued continuous function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$, is there an *open* subset $U$ of $\mathbb R$, containing all irrational numbers, and a continuous extension of $f$ to U?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enumerate the rationals as $\{q_n\}$ and define $f(x) = \sum_{n : q_n < x} 2^{-n}$.  Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ but cannot be extended continuously to any proper superset of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Wonderful !!!!!

Comment: I am writing a paper in which your nice example will fit marvelously, so I plan to cite this post, but I wonder if perhaps you have other sources I should also cite?

Comment: I don't remember where I first learned about this function, but I feel like it's "well known".  Gelbaum's *Counterexamples in Analysis* might have it.  I can check my copy later today.

Comment: This is Remark 4.31 in Rudin’s book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  A generalization of this is presented to show that the set of discontinuities of a monotonic function can be any countable set.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Just to let you know that @NateEldredge 's nice example has finally made it into the paper I was writting (https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09683).  It is used in an essential way in section (21), there.